# Ruby script for RPG Maker Ace VX, case sensitive ID is octal number

Tags: ruby, octal

I have inserted a script to make a Journal Quest written by Modern Algebra. It works perfectly but when I tried to input an Item ID, 128, I get an error telling me that the number is an octal. I tried converting the number into a string "128" but the program crashes. This is part of the code:

```
q[:name]              = "Fish for the Inn"

q[:icon_index]        = 028
```

I'm very new to Ruby. 
Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `q[:icon_index] = 128` not work?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake... I was very tired. The actual number is 028 - That's why it gets interpreted as an octal, because of the zero in front and the 8 in the number. It didn't happen with, for example, 023. By the way, are you the same Zack I met on Blender Stack Exchange?

Comment: I'm not that zack. Why are you entering the number with a leading zero?

Comment: also, 028 is not even a valid octal number.  Octal is digits 0-7

Comment: Exactly!I had no problem with other numbers starting with 0 which are not considered: INVALID OCTAL DIGITS - because octals do not contain a 8 or a 9.

This is the message error that I get:

Script "Quest Journal" line 794: SintaxError occured.

Invalid octal digit

q[icon:index] = 028

The items listed in the database start with 001 and so on so these are not numbers that can be altered as far as I understand because they are in the core of the program.

Comment: In the title I should have used INVALID OCTAL DIGIT...

Comment: Maybe don't use octal at all and just enter in the decimal number. Octal is an artifact of the ruby interpreter. The actual number is stored in binary. As far as ruby is concerned, 027 == 0x17 == 23 == 10111. It's all the same, and they all refer to the same number (or array index, or hash key)